# How to generate .ipa from xcode bot?

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, osx-server, xcode-bots

I am getting .xcarchive for my application when I am building using xcode bot and os x server. How can I get it to build .ipa?

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 7, you get a choice in the Bot configuration screen. Make sure to have the `Create user-installable product` option checked, this should create an `.ipa` from your archive automatically. (It actually creates an `.ipa` for every device type now since the introduction of app slicing).

[image: Xcode 7]

Answer (score 0):

When you build to OS X Server using bots, **both** an `xcarchive` and an `Ripa` are produced.

The "Product" button is a link to this `ipa`.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

When creating the scheme, check the Archive checkbox.

Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme...

[image: screenshot added on behalf of OP]

Comment: If you'd like to post a link to a screenshot, one of us can edit your post to include the image.

Comment: @JamesWebster how do I do that? I edited but I can't save due to
"You need at least 10 reputation to post images."

Comment: Just paste the link rather that using the add image tool

Comment: I would upvote your answer so that you have the privilege, but I don't *think* it's correct. But I'm not sure enough that it's wrong to down vote either.

Comment: @JamesWebster re-read you comment ... https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/5128916/9325225/425dd2f2-45c3-11e5-9105-5e4f92694809.png